# How to convert a registered version of an application back to a trial version when it is copied to another computer?

Tags: delphi, copy-protection, trialware, shareware

I would like to include some type of **copy protection scheme** on my applications that would make a **retail registered version** of my software **revert back to a trial version** of my software if/when it gets installed on another computer.

In the old days I would simply store all the user information in a record that I tacked on to the end of the exe file. During the registration process I would simply poke those values into the data record on the end of the exe file. This worked great until good ol Norton started flagging my product as a virus because the exe file changed.

I stopped doing that a long time ago. I'm getting ready to create an updated version of my software and I'd like to know how you have accomplshed this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information that makes it a retail version should be stored on the target computer, not with the original program.  That way, when they try to move the program, it reverts to the trial version because the retail information is missing on the new computer.

The retail information is added via a registration process, using a unique key.  There are a number of ways to make this key work only once.  One way is to transmit it directly to the program over the internet, where the user never sees it, so they can't manually transfer it to the new computer.

Comment: Besides using the internet, what other ways of key validation are there? Or where do you suggest I go to reseach this further?

Comment: Make the key time-sensitive (it's only good for 24 hours, according to the clock on the computer).  You can email it to your customer.

Answer (score 1):

You should save the information in multiple locations to minimize the chance a savvy user  can find it (using e.g. Process Monitor). I would suggest

- a registry key in HKCU and
- a hidden file in the local application directory.

Also save some information which is bound to the local computer, so even *if* the average user finds your file and registry entry copying won't succeed because they don't know how to obtain the updated data on a new PC. This information can also be a key generated by you based on some hardware ID the user has to send you.

Regarding the key generation algorithm: if the protection is "against" the average user then just make something up. This one depends a little bit on your target group. A simple one like [ROT47](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROT13) might be enough.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use the same thing.

Except in stead of saving the data in the exe (invoking a false positive of the AV) hash and save the data in a separate file.

Comment: Do you think that storing the info on the end of a dll would invoke a false positive? What if I also re-dated the dll to original date after I poked the data into the tail record?